# R: Importing CSV data based on multiple AND and OR conditions of the file names

Tags: r, regex, import, lapply

I need help in Importing CSV data based on multiple AND and OR conditions of the file names in R

I have a folder containing CSV files (820 in total), with each contains a fixed and identical format table, with different values populating the tables.

The CSV files can be categorized into multiple groups based on three variables: species, RCP, MSY. Please see below the table of the CSV filenames (file.dir) with the variables identified
[image: table]

I have 82 species (code), 2 RCPs and 5 MSYs, that totaled up to 820 CSV files/tables. I am currently using this code to import my csv, but my skill is limited to only one regular expression for "pattern=":

```
all_paths <- list.files(path = "C:/#File.dir", pattern = "rcp85", full.names = TRUE)
```

I wish to import the csv based on:

1. file names which has one of the names in the list of species (code) that is neither continuous nor in order. i.e. species codes in file name: **60002**,60005,**600042,600058**,600062,600089,**600092**,600100 (I want to select **bold** only)
2. import CSV file names containing either msy1 or msy3. Which means I wish to have both msy1 and msy3 imported simultaneously
3. Import the files in R with both conditions in (1) and (2) are met.

May I know how do I improve/express the script attached to meet my aim? or do I have to use extra packages to do so?

I hope my aims are not too confusing for anyone who reads it. Please do let m know if more information are required. Thanks a lot for your time!

Cheer,
Boo

Comment: Does this work? `list.files(path = "C:/#File.dir", pattern = "(60002|600042|600058|600092)-Biomass-\\w+-msy(1|3)\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: This works well!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea and it would not be the answer you exactly want, but it would be possible that you can make the list of file name with the species and MSY like this:

```
list.files <- list()
for(species in species.list) {
  for(rcp in c("rcp45","rcp85")){
    for(msy in c("msy1","msy3")){
      list.files <- append(list.files, paste0(species,"-Biomass-",rcp,"-",msy,".csv"))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great! I can import the data based on the file list I made